# Consuming WCF Service function that contains Params

Tags: .net, linux, wcf, web-services

I've created a WCF Service that contains only one function that takes parameters as below

```
int GetCount(string strServerPath, string strPort, params string[] arr_strItems)
```

And I published and added it as an application to Server IIS and I was able to consume it from my machine in ASP.NET application.

Now I need to consume it from a Linux based machine ,but when I do so below error appeared

> WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:strItem. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 414. Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. '.

Where the strItemis a variable used in the function as below

```
foreach (string strItem in arr_strItems)
                {
                    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(
                        XmlReader.Create(

                        strServerPath +
                        ":" +
                        strPort +

                        strItem
```

- What is the problem?
- Is it related to the params type? or the foreach code?
- How I can solve it?

Comment: Try capturing the request sent from both the ASP.NET application (which succeeds) and the linux app (which fails), and compare them. That should point you to the problem.

Comment: On linux it fails showing the above message which I didn't get what does it mean. I am not sure I can follow this approach.

Comment: You're showing the response received from the server; try capturing the HTTP request sent over the network. In Windows, Fiddler is always a good tool; on Linux I don't know, but there should be many...